# ms access rejecting case statement in sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to run this query in ms access but ms access keeps telling me there is a syntax error in the case statement. May you assist me in fixing my CASE statement please

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_number_of_followups_scheduled,
       COUNT(CASE  WHEN status = 'Completed' THEN 1 END) AS number_followups_completed
FROM   promis_lt
```

Answer (score 2):

MS Access doesn't support `CASE` expressions.  You need to use `IIF()` or `SWITCH()`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_number_of_followups_scheduled, 
       SUM(IIF(status = 'Completed', 1, 0 END)) AS number_followups_completed
FROM promis_lt
```